# Can hiring committee directly contact editors of journals

Tags: journals, recommendation-letter, reference-request, recruiting

Normally, a hiring committee gets references from those an applicant provides to them. However, in some cases, I wonder if a hiring committee can directly contact the editor of a journal who is in charge of the paper of the applicant.

I think this can happen if the paper of the applicant is still under review and the editor has yet to reach a decision. In this case, the applicant can not have the editor of his paper as a reference if he does not know him, but the hiring committee can not wait and want to contact the editor directly for the quality of the paper. Maybe the hiring committee needs to find an acquaintance of the editor in order to know his opinion on the paper.

Any thought on the above scenario?

Comment: I cannot imagine a hiring committee going to the trouble of contacting an editor for an opinion  on a submitted paper. Nor can I imagine an editor responding.

Comment: A hiring committee can find an acquaintance of the editor to know their opinion, right?

Comment: Why would a journal editor be a reference for, well, anything in a hiring process?

Comment: Suppose a hiring committee wants to know the quality of a paper to decide whether hire the paper's author or not.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because you seem to be arguing in the comments that you are really looking for a way to have a submitted paper (yours?) evaluated by a hiring committee. That's not an answerable question.

Comment: @Ethan Bolker, I do not want to have a submitted paper evaluated by a hiring committee. But I run into the problem described above, i.e. what happens to a paper that is important but can not be fully verified at the moment.

Comment: My feeling is that if a single paper is sufficiently good (significant, important, etc.) to make a nontrivial difference in the hiring of someone, then this should already be clear from the letters of recommendation, from [grapevine word-of-mouth in the field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grapevine_(gossip)), etc. Trying to explicitly call attention to the paper in such a way as you suggest would be a [red flag](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/red-flag) to me. In general, there are many, many more aspects about the suitability of a candidate than something like this.

Comment: What I am talking about could be a (very) rare case and generally nonexistent. Suppose someone has an important (great) paper but can not be fully verified in a short period of time, then few people can understand and so can not state it the letter of recommendation. But if the hiring committee likes it (very much) and can not wait because other institutions may make an offer, then it probably takes chance and makes an offer first. Before doing that, contacting the editor of the paper becomes a real possibility.

Comment: *Suppose someone has an important (great) paper* --- I suspect hiring committees are primarily interested in the likelihood of the candidate continuing to produce important papers **after** being hired. Having such a paper **before** being hired helps suggest this, but if nothing else about the candidate also suggests this, then how do they know you didn't just get lucky in some way? Incidentally, this all assumes that the position being hired for is mainly to "write important papers", not to teach courses, advise students, serve on committees, contribute to ongoing departmental research, etc.

Comment: I am talking about a (endowment) chair position and so it is mainly on research, not much else.

Answer (score 4):

I have never seen this happen and I can't imagine it happening either, because unless the journal editor is an expert on the exact topic (not likely), they are not especially qualified to comment on the quality of the paper. The most they can say is that the reviewers think [XYZ], and even then, the real review happens after publication.

That said, the contact information of journal editors is usually publicly available, so hiring committees can contact them. It's just that I don't see them doing it.

Comment: For "the real review happens after publication", what happens if a paper can not be fully verified for publication (this means the paper can not be published) but its importance is evident?

Comment: @hermes I don't understand. What do you mean by "can not be fully verified for publication (this means the paper can not be published)"? If the paper cannot be published because it is incorrect, then its importance is kind of irrelevant.

Comment: Sometimes people know a paper is of great importance (or potential) but they can not verify every detail of the paper because it is either too new or too hard so that no referees can be found.

Comment: This can happen (often). So a paper that cannot be published does mean it is incorrect or not important, which should be common sense.

Comment: @hermes are you referring to math papers? For the fields I'm familiar with the bar for publication is not that high. If you are referring to math papers, then my understanding is the paper is not published until review is done, and in the meantime the preprint is available. Contacting the editor then is still not helpful, because the editor doesn't know if the paper is good either.

Comment: @ Allure, yes, I am referring to papers in mathematics and other highly sophisticated fields, not ordinary ones.

Comment: Sometimes an editor should know the importance of the paper he is in charge of.

Comment: @hermes sounds improbable - a paper could deal with a very important topic, but if one cannot verify that the paper is correct, then the fact that the paper deals with a very important topic is irrelevant. It could be wrong, after all. E.g. there are plenty of wrong papers dealing with whether P = NP. Would you call them important?

Comment: @ Allure, that depends on the type of problems. In the proof of a conjecture, everything has to be verified because it can be declared true or important. But if the work is a theory (involving some philosophy), it often can not be verified every step. However, we can know it is important or not by intuition or something else.

Comment: @hermes but then the paper would be published wouldn't it? In the same way the papers on General Relativity, MOND, etc were published even though the theory wasn't (still aren't) fully verified. I cannot understand what you are writing; maybe a mathematician can answer.

Comment: @ Allure, that answers your claim "but if one cannot verify that the paper is correct, then the fact that the paper deals with a very important topic is irrelevant. ". So a paper can be published and deemed important without all of its detail being verified. You got a good example of relativity.

Comment: @hermes then the paper is published, there is still no "if a paper can not be fully verified for publication (this means the paper can not be published)", and the question that you asked in the OP doesn't arise. I still do not understand what you are writing.

Comment: @ Allure,  I mean that if some papers can not be fully verified for publication, then they can not be published. It does not hold for all papers. Note that there is "what happens if" before the sentence.